# What is the best dog repellent?

Tags: dogs

Lately I have dogpoo on my lawn daily . I was using a mix of vinegar+water  and cayenne pepper but this does not help. Anyone know of a effective dog repellent?

Comment: First thing would be trying to figure out which dog it is and whether it's going there on its own or with is owner (yes, such people exist). Is there a fence? Any more details? Maybe even pictures?